# Group by Date and sum of total duration for that day

Tags: postgresql

I am using workbench/j Postgres DB for my query which is as follows -

Input

```
ID  |utc_tune_start_time    |utc_tune_end_time
----------------------------------------------
A   |04-03-2019 19:00:00    |04-03-2019 20:00:00
----------------------------------------------
A   |04-03-2019 23:00:00    |05-03-2019 01:00:00
-----------------------------------------------
A   |05-03-2019 10:00:00    |05-03-2019 10:30:00
-----------------------------------------------
```

Output

```
ID  |Day        |Duration in Minutes
----------------------------------------
A   |04-03-2019 |120
-----------------------------------
A   |05-03-2019 |90
-----------------------------------
```

I require the duration elapsed from the utc_tune_start_time till the end of the day and similarly, the time elapsed for utc_tune_end_time since the start of the day.

Comment: A few clarifying questions: 1) Are the dates m-d-y or d-m-y?  It's often better to write them as y-m-d to avoid confusion.  2) I don't understand what duration you are talking about.  You say from utc_tune_start_time till end of day, which should be 5 hours for row 1 and 1 hour for row 2, but you show only 120 minutes total?

Comment: Hi, Im using dd-mm-yyyy. The first row has time spent for an ID. Therefore, when the end time falls in the next day. The group by clause should only take into duration for that day.

Comment: select *,
to_date(cast(utc_start_time as TEXT),'YYYY-MM-DD'), extract(minute from utc_start_time) as STB_Seconds from table
union
select *,
to_date(cast(utc_original_end_time as TEXT),'YYYY-MM-DD'), extract(minute from utc_original_end_time) as STB_Seconds from table

Comment: this was something - shared by a user... i cant seem to modify this to my requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your clarifications.  This is possible with some case statements.  Basically, if utc_tune_start_time and utc_tune_end_time are on the same day, just use the difference, otherwise calculate the difference from the end or start of the day.

```
WITH all_activity as (
   select date_trunc('day', utc_tune_start_time) as day, 
   case when date_trunc('day', utc_tune_start_time) = 
             date_trunc('day', utc_tune_end_time)
        then utc_tune_end_time - utc_tune_start_time
        else date_trunc('day', utc_tune_start_time) + 
             interval '1 day' - utc_tune_start_time 
   end as time_spent
from test
UNION ALL
    select date_trunc('day', utc_tune_end_time), 
    case when date_trunc('day', utc_tune_start_time) = 
              date_trunc('day', utc_tune_end_time) 
         then null -- we already calculated this earlier
         else utc_tune_end_time - date_trunc('day', utc_tune_end_time) 
    end
    FROM test
)
select day, sum(time_spent)
FROM all_activity
GROUP BY day;
         day         |   sum
---------------------+----------
 2019-03-04 00:00:00 | 02:00:00
 2019-03-05 00:00:00 | 01:30:00
(2 rows)
```

Comment: It works perfectly as required. Thank you!! I added the ID in the group by. Im having difficulty in creating a table using this script. create table before the with clause doesnt seem to work.

Comment: create temp table ts
(stb_id VARChar(256),day date, duration int);

insert into ts----/YOUR CODE/ select stb_id, day::date utc_tune_start_date, sum(extract(epoch from time_spent)/60) as duration
FROM all_activity
GROUP BY stb_id, utc_tune_start_date;

Comment: It should work like this: create temp table ts AS /MY CODE/.